# Angular Material: Add new row without refreshing table

Tags: angular, uitableview, angular-material

In my project, I'm using Angular6 with angular-material designs. In my table, I have to add new data row into an existing table without refreshing the whole table.
Here is what I have tried so far,

#### `issue-data.component.ts`

```
export class IssueDataComponent implements OnInit {

  addStatus() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    this.modelData = {
      list: this.IssueDataDTOList,
      type: "add",
      toBeEditedDTO: null
    }

    dialogConfig.data = this.modelData;
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;//disable default close operation
    dialogConfig.width = '30%';

    this.dialog.open(EditIssueDataComponent, dialogConfig).afterClosed().subscribe(
      res => {
        //updating data source array
        this.updatingDataSource(res);
      }
    )
  }

  updatingDataSource(result) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

}
```

#### `edit-issue-data.component.ts`

```
export class EditIssueDataComponent implements OnInit {

  statusForm: FormGroup;
  IssueDataDTOList = [];
  statusArray: string[] = ['Active', 'Inactive'];
  isStatusExist = false;
  dataFromParent = { list: [], type: '', toBeEditedDTO: { id: 0, name: '', backlog: '', status: '' } };

  constructor(private matDialogRef: MatDialogRef<DefineCalenderComponent>,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private issueService: IssueService,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<any>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataFromParent = this.data;
    this.IssueDataDTOList = this.dataFromParent.list;
      this.statusForm = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        backlog: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        // status: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      });
  }

  addStatus() {
    const IssueDataDTO = {};
      IssueDataDTO['name'] = this.statusForm.value.name;
      IssueDataDTO['backlog'] = this.statusForm.value.backlog;
      IssueDataDTO['status'] = "ACTIVE";

    this.issueService.updateIssueData(IssueDataDTO).subscribe(res => {
      this.IssueDataDTOList.push(res);
      this.cancelPopup();
    }
    );
  }
```

Following is my service class,

```
export class IssueService {
    public statusesId; 
    private apiURL = environment.apiUrl;


    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    issueDataForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        statusesId: new FormControl(-1), 
        issueStatus: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        showInBacklog: new FormControl(''),
        status: new FormControl('')
      });
 issueStatusDTOList= [];
UpdateStatus(data): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.apiURL + 'saveStatus', data);
      }}
```

but when I'm trying to add new data the result is as follows,
[image]

All data are gone and screen displays only the data I have added recently.

Comment: So much code; can you highlight where are adding new items to your data source?

Comment: in edit-issue-data.component.ts @JeffryHouser

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake, can you please check `this.dataSource.data` before `this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data, result]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not need to do

> this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);
>   this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator; this.dataSource.sort =
>   this.sort;

use

```
this.dataSource.data.push(result);
this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription();
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try with that if it works i'll offer my bounty

Comment: wow, such an answer you deserve it thank you very much. very helpfull answer

Comment: does this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription(); update only the new data? or does this refresh the table?

Comment: I'll offer bounty tomorow

Comment: What is the difference between `this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data, result];` and `this.dataSource.data.push(result);` in this case? Why there's no undefined in the `...push()` way?

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake it is mat-table api which will update u'r datasource when you do operations on it like push(),splice() etc.

Comment: got it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

After you request for update you need to request for data that's been updated

```
 updatingDataSource(result) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    requestForNewDataSourceFnc()
  }
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try with that if it works i'll offer my bounty

Answer (score 0):

Try not to create a new `MatTableDataSource` on update but rather add new data to the existing. Something like this:

```
updatingDataSource(result) {
    this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data, result];
}
```

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake can you create a stackblitz with the example and recheck the code, because those 3 lines I sent are ok. Shouldn't be any error.

Comment: this is a part of very large project so it can't be shown in slackblitz

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake does your editor show you where is the error exactly? Can you send that piece of code?

Comment: updatingDataSource(result) {
    this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data, result];
}

Comment: after (result) and before {

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake is that a separate method in your code?

Comment: You have a method `updatingDataSource()` in the `issue-data.component.ts`, just replace it with the code I sent

Comment: functionality working but there is an exeption I have updated my question plese take a look

Comment: Can you send an example of the `this.dataSource.data` (couple of elements would be enough) and an example of the `result`?

Comment: Difficult to say, try to check if you don't call the method `updatingDataSource()` before `this.dataSource.data` is defined.